# How do I set key binding for set mark in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

*I'm new to emacs and newer to lisp*

I'm trying to set Meta + spacebar to set the mark for highlighting text (at current cursor position).
searching around online and experimenting I've ended up with the command

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") 'push-mark nil nil 1)`

The above command isn't working for me though, I'm getting an "incorrect number of arguments error".

Got the function definition,

  push-mark &optional position nomsg activate

[from elisp manual here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-21-2.8/html_node/elisp_491.html)

  **Position:**
  nil for position should default to current cursor position

  **nomsg:**
  I don't care about (I think)

  **activate:**
  apparently isn't true by default so I need to set it to...something.

How would I format the command to pass in three values?

*The error is definitely due to the push-mark function call as other functions such as backward-char (which I'm not passing inputs to) work correctly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your arguments to `push-mark`, not `global-set-key`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") (lambda() (interactive) (push-mark nil nil 1)))
```